# Stop samba share from unmounting at signoff WinServ22

Tags: redhat, samba, network-share, database-backup, windows-server-2022

I am trying to find a way to map a drive so that it will not unmount when I sign out of the system.

I currently have a backup job running from the SQL management console and it is aimed at a samba share on a rhel box. Things work fine at the moment as long as I am logged into the windows box. When I sign off though, the drive unmounts and the job does not complete.

I do not have a specific error code but I am working to get that now. Is this seeminly possible or is there a better solution than this for automating backups from sql to a samba share?

Comment: please look to [ask]. Inhere is missing a tons of information. we can't use our glass balls all the time to imagine all system configurations ;)